# How to activate Markdown in a local installation of WordPress 4.3?

Tags: posts, options, markdown

As of version 4.3. it should be possible to activate markdown for my posts and comments (http://news.softpedia.com/news/say-hello-to-wordpress-4-3-489688.shtml).

I found a description on https://en.support.wordpress.com/markdown/ , but the settings mentioned are not visible in `settings -> writing` and `settings -> discussion`.

- My role is `Administrator`
- The installed version is `Version 4.3`

Answer (score 3):

WordPress 4.3 have **no markdown implementation**, it is only a short list of shortcuts.
The shortcuts active on default. It give no UI area to active/deactivated them.
As small hint for updates posts. I seen often, that works only on new posts, no old drafts. But I haven't debug this.

#### Which Formatting Shortcuts

WordPress 4.3 came with a new feature called formatting shortcuts. It allows users to quickly add common text formatting without removing their hands from the keyboard and without writing any HTML.

- Using * or – will start an unordered list.
- Using 1. or 1) will start an ordered list.
- Using # will transform into h1. ## for h2, ### for h3 and so on.
- Using > will transform into blockquote.

#### Deactivate shortcuts

The only way to deactivate is a small piece of code, like in a simple custom plugin.

```
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'fb_disable_mce_wptextpattern' );
function fb_disable_mce_wptextpattern( $opt ) {

    if ( isset( $opt['plugins'] ) && $opt['plugins'] ) {
        $opt['plugins'] = explode( ',', $opt['plugins'] );
        $opt['plugins'] = array_diff( $opt['plugins'] , array( 'wptextpattern' ) );
        $opt['plugins'] = implode( ',', $opt['plugins'] );
    }

    return $opt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try [Markdown Editor plugin](https://terryl.in/en/repository/wordpress-markdown-plugin-githuber-md/). It supports WordPress 4.0 - 5.3

Source code: https://github.com/terrylinooo/githuber-md

[image]